# How to prevent status bar from showing in fullscreen mode on click

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

I use the code below to enable fullscreen mode:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                );
```

At android 5 all is ok, but at android 4.3 status bar (and nav bar) are opened afrer 'click' action on any button, so I need to tap twice.
How to prevent this control from showing on `onClick`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

in your manifest.

Comment: What about solution for appcompact?